# Is tower/creep strength based on number of players?

Tags: league-of-legends

For the standard 5v5, if someone disconnects does their tower/creep stats change? I saw it mentioned on a forum that the tower/creeps get stronger if someone leaves.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Short answer: No

Long Answer: At one time, Turrets *used* to gain attack damage and attack speed for each allied champion near the tower, but this is no longer the case.

Turrets *do* gain attack damage as time elapses, and they *do* gain armor if there are no minions around (this is to discourage backdooring), but these happen regardless of the number of players connected to the game.

Additionally, Turrets *lose* armor and magic resistance as time elapses. This is to encourage quicker overall games.

Comment: Neat, the bit about gaining armor with no  minions is particularly interesting. Do you have a source/ratios on the attack gain over time/armor bonus?

Comment: I found some data [here](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Tower) but I haven't verified it for myself.

Comment: I thought that the towers did more *damage* if there were no minions around, not that they gained armor. Huh. I guess I had that wrong.

Comment: @Grace - well, they do deal more damage the longer they're focused on a single target, which, in the absence of minions, might give you that impression. Their damage lowers whenever they switch targets.

Answer (score 3):

Both neutral and non-neutral creeps don't gain any stats when someone disconnects.
They gain stats as the time elapses.

Comment: Hey Pierre, welcome to the site. The question here's more about whether or not creeps gain stats when someone disconnects; I would recommend editing your answer to focus on that aspect of creeps.

Comment: No problem! Once you get 50 reputation on the site you'll be able to leave comments to reply to this kind of stuff.